# Настройка rewrite_rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Доброго времени суток 
При первом посещении сайта юзер выбирает город и его перекидывает на нужную поддиректорию, после чего нужно открывать страницы именно этой директории
Необходимо все ссылки заменять по шаблону `site.ru/example/` на `site.ru/userCity/example` где userCity это кука
Пытался использовать, но не смог исправить под все страницы

```apache
# Редирект на каталог с городом, если нет в запросе ключа noredirect
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*noredirect.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/catalog
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} CITY=([^;]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L,R=302]

# По обращению на каталог города проксируем запрос на основной каталог с запретом редиректа
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[^\/]+/catalog(.*)
RewriteRule .+ /catalog%1?noredirect [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Это у вас уже третья попытка вопроса? Я вам уже говорил раньше, все запросы шлите в index.php, а там обрабатывайте как вам нужно и не мучайтесь с правилами в .htaccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Редирект на основе куки, если еще не на странице какого-то города
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*noredirect.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} CITY=([^;]+) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(irkutsk|krasnoyarsk|rostov|khabarovsk)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L,R=302]

# По обращению на страницу города проксируем запрос на основной сайт с запретом редиректа
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(irkutsk|krasnoyarsk|rostov|khabarovsk)/(.*)
RewriteRule .+ /%2?noredirect [L,QSA]
```